# How to find and replace text in between two tags in HTML or XML document using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I want to find and replace text in a HTML document between, say inside the <title> tags. For example,

```
var str = "<html><head><title>Just a title</title></head><body>Do nothing</body></html>";
var newTitle = "Updated title information";
```

I tried using parseXML() in jQuery (example below), but it is not working:

```
var doc= $($.parseXML(str));
doc.find('title').text(newTitle);
str=doc.text();
```

Is there a different way to find and replace text inside HTML tags? Regex or may be using replaceWith() or something similar?

Comment: do you mean, you want to replace a portion of the selected tag's text?

Comment: yes, basically replace the text inside <title> tags in the "str" variable

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I did something similar in a question earlier today using regexes:

```
str = str.replace(/<title>[\s\S]*?<\/title>/, '<title>' + newTitle + '<\/title>');
```

That should find and replace it. `[\s\S]*?` means [any character including space and line breaks]any number of times, and the ? makes the asterisk "not greedy," so it will stop (more quickly) when it finds `</title>`.

Comment: I missed a \ to escape the / in </title>. Updated.

Comment: Coming back to this answer two years later to revise. Future stackoverflow users should prefer @Dimitar's method, my method has a slight risk of [summoning Cthulhu](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) and probably suffers much greater speed losses from file size.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do something like this:

```
var doc = $($.parseXML(str));
doc.find('title').text(newTitle);

// get your new data back to a string 
str = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(doc[0]);
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z89dL/1/

Answer (score 1):

This would be a wonderful time to use Javascript's `stristr(haystack, needle, bool)` method. First, you need to get the head of the document using `$('head')`, then get the contents using `.innerHTML`.

For the sake of the answer, let's store `$('head').innerHTML` in a `var` called `head`. First, let's get everything before the title with `stristr(head, '<title>', true)`, and what's after the title with `stristr(head, '</title>')` and store them in `var`s called `before` and `after`, respectively. Now, the final line is simple:

```
head.innerHTML = before + "<title>" + newTitle + after;
```

Comment: this seems interesting. Would it be possible to provide a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: oh whoops! ah i feel stupid now...sorry, I was getting myself confused with PHP...this would work in a PHP file, but not a JS one.