# Replace HTML between two tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want to do is replace what is in between two HTML tags.

I'm using this as a reference but I'm still encountering problems:
[REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024971/jquery-how-to-replace-all-between-certain-characters)

This is what I've tried:

```
el.getValue().replace(/<form.+<\/form>/, "<div></div>");
```

I need to replace all my form tags dynamically.

Comment: Never use Regex to amend HTML, lest you awaken [Tony the Pony](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Assuming you're amending elements in the DOM, then just `$('form').empty().append('<div />');` will do what you need

Comment: You should'nt use regex to modify HTML, you'll end up with [lea͠ki̧n͘g fr̶ǫm ̡yo​͟ur eye͢s̸ ̛l̕ik͏e liq​uid pain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Thou shall not use regex to parse HTML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery change text between two elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118054/jquery-change-text-between-two-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah. I found a solution.

```
el.getValue().replace(/<form[\s\S]*?<\/form>/, "<div></div>");
```

Explanation by @[James G]:
`[\s\S]*?` means [any character including space and line breaks]any number of times, and the ? makes the asterisk "not greedy," so it will stop (more quickly) when it finds `</form>`.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779071/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-between-two-tags-in-html-or-xml-document-using-j)

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, just retrieve the parent element of what you'd like to be replaced, and replace the content with the `.html()` function.

Ex:

```
var formParentElement = $('#formParentElement');
formParentElement.html("<div>my new content</div>");
```

If you don't use jQuery:

```
var formParentElement = document.getElementById("formParentElement");
formParentElement.innerHTML = "<div>my new content</div>";
```

The example assumes the parent element of your form has an ID with value "formParentElement".